# How to find and format latest date from multiple fields in xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have searched for info on my specific scenario and did not find what I'm looking for. Apologies up front if I missed something.

I am looking for help on syntax for finding and formatting the latest date out of a set of three fields.  I am able to sloppily find the latest date and am able to format a date, but putting the syntax all together and getting it to work properly is eluding me.  I wanted to ask this forum for a clean code to do the following:
Using xslt 2.0 find, return and format the latest date out of these three fields - format of '20070724' :
            -ws:Pay_Rate_Type_Change_Effective_Date
            -ws:Time_Type_Change_Effective_Date
            -ws:Job_Code_Change_Effective_Date

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks,
Jenn

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ws:Worker_Sync xmlns:ws="urn:com.workday/workersync"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<ws:Worker>
    <ws:Summary>
        <ws:Employee_ID>123456</ws:Employee_ID>
    </ws:Summary>
    <ws:Additional_Information>
        <ws:Time_Type_Change_Effective_Date>2005-05-24</ws:Time_Type_Change_Effective_Date>
        <ws:Pay_Rate_Type_Change_Effective_Date>2006-06-24</ws:Pay_Rate_Type_Change_Effective_Date>
        <ws:Job_Code_Change_Effective_Date>2007-07-24</ws:Job_Code_Change_Effective_Date>
    </ws:Additional_Information>
</ws:Worker>    
</ws:Worker_Sync>


<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ws="urn:com.workday/workersync" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt" xmlns:etv="urn:com.workday/etv"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report">
<!-- set encoding of output - need to create a properly formatted XML document that Workday's internal document transformation engine will convert to a text file -->
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <File xtt:separator="&#xd;&#xa;">
        <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xa;'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="currentDate">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-date(current-date(), '[Y0001][M01][D01]')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ws:Worker_Sync/ws:Worker"/>
    </File>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/ws:Worker_Sync/ws:Worker">
    <Record xtt:separator="|">
        <EmployeeAssignedID>
            <xsl:value-of select="ws:Summary/ws:Employee_ID"/>
        </EmployeeAssignedID>            
        <RecordChangeEffectiveDate/>         <!--FT/PT, Hrly/Slry, Jobcode change effdt-->
        <!--Here is where I have to add code to say:
        Find, return and format the latest date out of these three fields in xml file - format of '20070724' :
        -ws:Pay_Rate_Type_Change_Effective_Date
        -ws:Time_Type_Change_Effective_Date
        -ws:Job_Code_Change_Effective_Date    -->   
    </Record>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XPath alone can do that, select the three elements: `ws:Pay_Rate_Type_Change_Effective_Date, ws:Time_Type_Change_Effective_Date, ws:Job_Code_Change_Effective_Date`, convert each into `xs:date`: `(ws:Pay_Rate_Type_Change_Effective_Date, ws:Time_Type_Change_Effective_Date, ws:Job_Code_Change_Effective_Date)/xs:date(.)`, then take the maximum `max((ws:Pay_Rate_Type_Change_Effective_Date, ws:Time_Type_Change_Effective_Date, ws:Job_Code_Change_Effective_Date)/xs:date(.))`. Then `format-date` that value.

Comment: Hi Martin,Thanks for replying. I used a bit of your idea, added some co-worker input and then played around with syntax for a bit.  I posted my final working code below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the complete answer to my question with some help from Martin, co-workers and my own trial and error.  Here is what I ended up using and it works perfectly.

```
<RecordChangeEffectiveDate>            
 <xsl:value-of select="format-date(max((xs:date(ws:Additional_Information/ws:Pay_Rate_Type_Change_Effective_Date), xs:date(ws:Additional_Information/ws:Time_Type_Change_Effective_Date), xs:date(ws:Additional_Information/ws:Job_Code_Change_Effective_Date) )), '[Y0001][M01][D01]') "/>
</RecordChangeEffectiveDate>
```